# UITabBar customization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

This looks like a long shot, but does anyone know of a way to:

1. Position a UITabBar on the top part of the screen
2. Change it's height

You are welcome to suggest private API methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need private API, just try this in your applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

```
controller = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

HeadlinesViewController *headlines = [[HeadlinesViewController alloc] init];
OpinionsViewController *opinions = [[OpinionsViewController alloc] init];

controller.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:headlines, opinions, nil];

    // set your position , width and height there
controller.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50);
[window addSubview:controller.view ];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a category to change the tabbar's height

you can check this out [UITabBar height in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741921/uitabbar-height-in-ios-5/18868573#18868573)

hope it will help you :)