# Change tabbar size and color iphone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

They say that Apple doesn't let apps with custom tabbar color or height in. Is it true? I want to change the height of both navigationbar as well as tabbar in my application. Is it ok?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568727/uitabbar-customization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/SpecialViews/SpecialViews.htmlBlue) :

> You can specify the color and
> translucency of a navigation bar to
> coordinate with the overall look of
> your application and with the other
> bars in it (that is, toolbars, tab
> bars, and the status bar). You can use
> a custom color or choose one of the
> standard colors:
>
> Blue (the default color)
>
> BlackBlue (the default color) Black

Now I don't think it is possible to change their height.