# Want tabbed window effect like in windows properties for I-Phone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to i-phone development.
as per my project requirement i want a tabbed window browsing effect like the one you see in window-XP display properties or in IE internet options.

i have found that tab bar controller is there in iphone .
but that tab bar comes at the bottom..
i want it on the top.

looking for your support.

Thanks,
DSOXT

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would follow UI convention. Different platforms work in different ways, and a tab bar on top is "strange" on a iOS (or even Android) device. Pounding Windows conventions (which are actually now relegated to history - tab bars are disappearing in Windows) into iOS is silly.

However, if you REALLY want to do this, this may work: [UITabBar customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568727/uitabbar-customization) (untested by me)