# Is it possible in ios to have the navigation bar stay as in rather then moving through the view hierarchy on click?

Tags: ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios4

Is it possible in ios to have the navigation bar stay as is, in rather then moving through the view hierarchy on click?
What I want is a standard 5 button navigation and when I click on an item it gives me a view transition and highlights the navbar item without changing the nav bar by moving it down the hierarchy. apologies if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could do this, but you're effectively rolling your own UITabBarController.  If you haven't already, read it's [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You can place the tab bar at the top of your screen if that's what you want.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2568727/470879).

If you still want to create your own version with the Navigation Bar, then don't use a UINavigationController.  Instead you could use a UIViewController subclass with a Navigation bar, and a UISegmentedControl.  The [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) Sample code project shows how to implement this.

Then in the IBAction for your segmented control, do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender {

int selectedIndex = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];

switch (selectedIndex) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"segment 0 selected");
        //perform transition and switch views here
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"segment 1 selected");
        //perform transition and switch views here
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"segment 2 selected");
        //perform transition and switch views here
        break;
    default:
        break;
}  
}
```