# iOS iPhone Add label and text field below tab control

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm a beginner with iOS apps, and I inherited an app I need to make some changes to.

The main view of the app is a tab view, and we'd like to add below the tab view a box with some labels (and text). The labels shouldn't change as the tabs change.

How do I do this?

I noticed something called a SplitView, but I wasn't sure how to use it, and if it's relevant for my need.

I hope that my needs are clear enough. If anyone could make recommendations as to how to do it/point me in the direction of a tutorial, I'd be very appreciate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The UISplitView is only for iPads. It will not work on the iPhone as far as I know. How are you creating your UITabBar. If you do it programatically you might be able to create it like something like this:

Pseudo Code

```
 UITabBarController *mySpecialController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake('put in coordinates here')];
```

Comment: Here is a good one I found for UITabBar Customization:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568727/uitabbar-customization

Comment: i looked there, do you know if he's referring to this method

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 User *user = [[User alloc] init];
    
 if ([user isActive]) {
  [self startApp];
 }
 else {
  NSString *status = [user getStatus];
  SubscriptionController *subCont  = [[SubscriptionController alloc] initWithStatus:status];
  [window addSubview:subCont.view];
 }
 
 [user release];
 
 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}